# Drag 'n Drop with Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, grid

I am looking for a jQuery/vanilla javascript plugin that has the functionality to place in grid - Horizontal + vertical. Like photoshop grids. And has IDs or something like that (or easy to implent).

I need the IDs to give something of a value to that ID so I can see where an item is dropped. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: "functionality to place" **what** in the grid? Photoshop grids are designed to allow the alignment or snapping of elements, not rearranging... your question makes little sense

Comment: Ooh I wasn't clear, sorry. I meant like that kind of grids, most of the plugins out there use just horizontal or vertical grids, I need squares to drop them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your post is semi vague I will do my best to just describe...

I use the jQueryUI Draggable/Droppable functions. With this you can make your own grid as you see fit and tie in the jQueryUI to get the drag n' drop you desire.

Comment: How to get JqueryUI working with Smartphone touch events?

Comment: That is a good question. I would search the stack and see if this topic has been covered. If it hasn't, ask the question. I bet someone somewhere has some experience or can point you in the right direction.